# How to track single folder traffic in Google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have forum directory on my website. That sub directory is located on http://www.mobilestore.pk/forum I was wondering that how can I track forum traffic only as a separate property in Google Analytics without filtering it from the whole traffic of the website. So I can show the trends of forum to Moderators or Editors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend using a property to break out traffic on the same domain. It's better to use a new view with a filter. Be sure to keep a view that is unfiltered.

If you do decide to use a separate property, you will need to modify the code in all the page templates used in the /forum path to use a different UA tracking ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a 2nd tracker for just the forum.

As per Google:
"In some cases you might want to send data to multiple web properties from a single page. This is useful for sites that have multiple owners overseeing sections of a site; each owner could view their own web property."

This exactly fits your scenario

See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#multipletrackers